# Could not copy the file .xbf because it was not found

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2019

When I build my project it gives me errors after the VS upgrade to 16.4.

As per the Output window on the screenshot you can see now VS tries to refer to a path for xbf files that includes the namespace as well. Previously it was not.

[image]

Eg: Previous path looks like this:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4570,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\AzureDevOps-Workspace\UWP\Main\PDFViewCtrlTools_VS2015\bin\x64\Debug\Utilities\SignatureDialog.xbf

The new path has an additional folder, consists namespace of the class. “pdftron.PDF.Tools”.

Why is this happening? On the old path, all the xbf files are available. But due to the new path reference VS gives errors like “it was not found.”

I tried cleaning my solution, deleting all the bin and obj folder from all projects and rebuilding. Removing project references and readding it. Nothing works.

Comment: Hi, Which project's csproj you're requesting? Please note that all class library projects build successfully when building individually. The above error happens when I try to build the main UWP project. "BoardPACWinApp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem with the same project in Visual Studio after updating to 16.4.1. After searching VS's known issue list, I came across the solution provided by Andrew Bares in the link below and it is working for me.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/845490/unable-to-run-uwp-project.html

Comment: Thank you very much. You've saved lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion of @jb1927. Please goto project properties -> build tab -> under the output section -> tick the checkbox "Generate library layout"

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the org post in the MS developer community. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/845490/unable-to-run-uwp-project.html

Comment: NOTE: Each time you change your solution platform (x86, x64 or ARM) and solution configuration ?(debug, release) this value has to set separately. So all together this has to set 6 times separately)

Comment: SusenSaluka, not true.  On the project's build tab, change both the Configuration and Platform to "All" and check this box.  Then you will see that all configs have the setting.

Comment: @RashadRivera Thanks for the update. I never tried that.